Cannot enable webcam on Ubuntu Server 20.04
I've been urgently trying to host a webserver where my USB camera is broadcast. I know every software I have tried so far works. However, suddenly Ubuntu is no longer able to read my webcam.
Running lsusb returns:
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 534d:2109 MacroSilicon USB Video which is what I need.
But trying to access this device in any other software is proving impossible, with errors such as:
Failed to open /dev/video0: Input/output error.
I know this isn't a permission error, and I know the camera works perfectly fine.
(The camera is technically an HDMI capture card, but functions as a usb webcam)
Any help appreciated!

I wonder if this will be helpful: Making the Macrosilicon MS2109 HDMI-to-USB capture device work on Linux
